# UnboundLocalError in Selenium with Python on my automated testing QA framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am very new to programming and Selenium in general but based on a course, I am trying to create a framework for the automated tests for my company and I have been trying to make it in a way that I can reuse the code as much as possible and implement the best practices.

I have my code almost exactly as the one of the course (Software Testing Mentor on YouTube) and I just change that relative to my testcases.

I have a setup function inside a fixture in my conftest.py file and then other files where I create functions of steps I will reuse in my cases and another file with all the locators that I need from where I import them.

My issue is that something is wrong in the way I setup the driver because I keep getting the following error:

ERROR at setup of test_coupons_03_Search_by_Title __________________________________

request = <SubRequest 'setup' for >

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup():
```

> ```
>   chrome_options = Options()
> ```

E       UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'driver' where it is not associated with a value

testcases\conftest.py:10: UnboundLocalError
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
ERROR test_couponRules.py::test_coupons_03_Search_by_Title - UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'driver' where it is not associated with a value

This is my conftest.py code:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromedriver_path = "C:\\Users\\marti\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32"

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://staging.admin.convercus.io/con/login")

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    request.cls.wait = wait

    yield

    driver.quit()
```

And this is the code of the file with the test case (I currently just have 1 test case just to test the framework since my idea is to import 359 tests that i currently have running in another framework):
NOTE: bear in mind that

```
        lp = LoginPage(self.driver, self.wait)
        lp.login
        ov = overviewPage(self.driver, self.wait)
        ov.gotocouponsv3()
```

are just using the login steps from a separated file and another funciton to go to the relevant section of the webapp.

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pages.loginpage import LoginPage
from pages.overviewpage import overviewPage
load_dotenv()
from testdata.locators import *



@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
def test_coupons_03_Search_by_Title(self):
        # Being able to conduct a coupon search based on a Title 
        lp = LoginPage(self.driver, self.wait)
        lp.login
        ov = overviewPage(self.driver, self.wait)
        ov.gotocouponsv3()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".app-headline__subtitle")))
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,\'mat-input-0\')]").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").send_keys("100")
        assert "100" in self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.--long-text.--is-clickable.cdk-column-i18nFields.mat-column-i18nFields.ng-star-inserted > span').text
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").clear()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").send_keys("1 (do not delete)")
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.--long-text.--is-clickable.cdk-column-i18nFields.mat-column-i18nFields.ng-star-inserted > span")))
        assert "1 (do not delete)" in self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.--long-text.--is-clickable.cdk-column-i18nFields.mat-column-i18nFields.ng-star-inserted > span").text
        self.driver.close()
```